# Nhibernate QueryOver how can I make this query use async?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, nhibernate, queryover

For this new website I want to use async methods in NHibernate. I have this simple query using QueryOver API but I can't get this one to work with async.

It is a simple query with some where clauses that list all businesses. I want 20 of them each time I execute this.

**Query:**

```
BusinessListItem bli = null;
BusinessCategory bc = null;
Category c = null;
BusinessImage bi = null;
Image i = null;

var q = Session.QueryOver<Business>()
            .JoinAlias(x => x.Categories, () => bc)
            .JoinAlias(() => bc.Category, () => c)
            .JoinAlias(x => x.Images, () => bi, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
            .JoinAlias(() => bi.Image, () => i, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
            .Where(() => bc.IsMain);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_name))
            q.WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.Name).IsLike($"%{_name}%");

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_streetName))
            q.WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.StreetName).IsLike($"%{_streetName}%");

        if (_categoryId != null)
            q.Where(() => c.Id == _categoryId.Value);

        if (_subCategoryIds != null)
            q.WhereRestrictionOn(() => c.Id).IsIn(_subCategoryIds);

        return q.Select(
                Projections.Property<Business>(x => x.Id).WithAlias(() => bli.Id),
                Projections.Property<Business>(x => x.Name).WithAlias(() => bli.Name),
                Projections.Property("c.Name").WithAlias(() => bli.CategoryName),
                Projections.Property("bi.Image").WithAlias(() => bli.Image)
            )
            .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<BusinessListItem>())
            .List<BusinessListItem>()
            .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
            .Skip(_skipCount)
            .Take(20)
            .ToList();
```

I know the method .ListAsync() exists but I cannot get it working together with the Skip, Take and OrderBy method.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Why aren't you incorporating your ordering and row restriction before you materialise the results? If you do this you should be able to use the `ListAsync()` method and get a, potentially, more efficient query.

Comment: @DavidOsborne How do you mean, materialise the results? I don't understand what u are saying.

Comment: When you call `List()` NH will take your query, build the SQL and then run it. If you then use extension methods, LINQ or otherwise, on the returned results, you're not getting the benefits an RDBMS can provide. Of course, sometimes this is intentional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this question is :

```
var result = await q.Select(
                Projections.Distinct(
                    Projections.Property<Business>(x => x.Id).WithAlias(() => bli.Id)
            )
            .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<BusinessListItem>())
            .OrderBy(x => x.Name).Asc
            .Skip(_skipCount)
            .Take(_takeCount)
            .ListAsync<BusinessListItem>();

        return result.ToList();
```

Thx to @DavidOsborne